# AngularJS: searching data client side by custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

i am learning angular. so i am not good in angular. i am showing data in tabular format with the help of `ng-repeat`. i have **one dropdown and textbox for filter data** showing by `ng-repeat`. fields name are populated in dropdown. so user will select field name and put corresponding value in textbox and search will perform accordingly and data will be shown.

my code is working partially. basically some kind of problem is there in `SearchList function`. the problem is when trying to search by id then `SearchList` is not working properly. so looking for help. what to fix in the code. my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/rnoo3bqc/6/

```
$scope.SearchList = function(row) {

    if ($scope.selectedFieldName && $scope.searchText) {
      var propVal = row[$scope.selectedFieldName.toLowerCase()];
      if (propVal) {
        return propVal.toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toUpperCase()) > -1;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;    
  };
```

### working version url

https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/rnoo3bqc/8/

Comment: The code was taken from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698164/angularjs-custom-search-data-by-writing-custom-filter/36698321#36698321, which this question is somewhat a duplicate of. Your question points out a bug in the accepted answer of the original question. I've corrected this issue and updated the answer and associated codepen. Not sure why you chose to ask a new question instead of improving the existing answer, but nice catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the id's from number to string, e.g. by concatenating an empty string:

```
var propVal = row[$scope.selectedFieldName.toLowerCase()] + '';
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was with `id` that's a `numeric` field and hence `toUpperCase()` was failing for it.

```
if (propVal) {
     propVal.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toUpperCase()) > -1; 
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: actually you can directly convert all the propVal value to string. so no 'if' anymore `if(propVal) return propVal.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toUpperCase()) > -1;`