# Angular Operator Searching

Tags: angularjs, search, html-table

I have an angular page with a search bar. I have successfully implemented a search bar and also improved it by using the [advanced search box](http://dnauck.github.io/angular-advanced-searchbox/). The table that I have has 2 columns. 1 for the user's name and 2 for the number of items the user has in his/her inventory. This is how the user object comes back in json:

```
{
    "displayName":"John",
    "items": [
        {
            "name":"foo1",
            "type":"fooType1"
        },
        {
            "name":"foo2",
            "type":"fooType2"
        },
        {
            "name":"foo3",
            "type":"fooType3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Angular's `$http` saves that in a data object and all I have to do is say `data.items.length`. So in my table I would display:

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Items |
+------+-------+
| John |     3 |
+------+-------+
```

I want to implement operator searching. So I want the user to be able to say `find all users with at least 3 items` or `find all users with more than 1 item but less than 5`. But I have yet to find any search bar features that supports this kind of operator searching. Is there a way to do it with this plugin?

Additionally, is there a way to make these searched case sensitive or search the whole word instead of other words that may contain the search query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you're going to have to call a function to do more advanced searching. I answered a similar question the other day and posted some code that does that here: [AngularJS custom search data by writing custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698164/angularjs-custom-search-data-by-writing-custom-filter/) it should help you to get started. If you're following the approach taken here you'd probably add a drop down for operator and the modify the function to take into account the operator as well.