# JavaScript Selecting Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Background: There's a table from which I can choose employees. I want to filter these employees by name.(I know name is not a good way to filter, this is just an example)
Basically I have a drop down from which I choose one of the filters.

My declaration: `$scope.filters = null;`.
I also have this deceleration to choose my filter `$scope.chosenFilter= null;`.

I use the following to retrieve the different filters I have `$scope.filters = retrieveFilters(info.Names);`

retrieveFilters looks like the following:

```
var retrieveFilters = function(rows) {

    var filterWrapper = document.querySelector(".filterWrapper");
    var datasetOptions = [];

    $scope.predicate = 'Name';

    if (rows) {
        //Add Default option
        datasetOptions.push({
            name: $scope.data.Fnames.defaultFilterOptionLabel,
            value: ''
        });
        $scope.chosenFilter = datasetOptions[0];

        _.forEach(rows, function(ele) {
            datasetOptions.push({
                name: ele,
                value: ele
            });
        });
    } else {
        filterWrapper.style.display = "none";
            }

    return datasetOptions;
};
```

I use the following to choose my filter:

```
$scope.$watch('chosenFilter', function() {
    var filterSearchInput = document.querySelector(".filterWrapper input");
    ng.element(filterSearchInput).triggerHandler('input');
});
```

Everything is fine and the display works on first load as I have set the default with

```
//Add Default option
datasetOptions.push({
    name: $scope.data.Fnames.defaultFilterOptionLabel,
    value: ''
});
```

From the default table whenever I click on an employees name hes details are displayed. However whenever I filter and click on the employees name, nothing is displayed. Whenever I click on a specific employees name at the default table and then filter in the same name the information also shows up, as I cache it each time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're displaying this data somewhere in your GUI using ng-repeat. Angular has a lot of great built-in features for this. Check out the answer here: [AngularJS custom search data by writing custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698164/angularjs-custom-search-data-by-writing-custom-filter/36698321#36698321) for a way to approach this more from an Angular direction. You also might want to check out this question and answer: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542).

Comment: Yes I am displaying using ng-repeat and the data displays fine whenever I choose a specific name from the options. However when i click on the actual row which is there no information is displayed. But if I click on the row in the default table, the one that's not "Filtered", the information does display. I just can't get the information to display whenever it is filtered, it is therefore what has me thinking I am doing the filtering the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah, check out the filtering in the question I linked to above. In short, ng-repeat has built-in filtering and making use of it is generally the way to go.